# I can't get jQuery hover events to trigger in FireFox over <area> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, area

I think this may not have anything to do with the area tags, but it could be I guess.

here is a link to download my source code since it is very hard to explain
http://temp-share.com/show/YgFHjkPEy

Do you have any idea how to get the same functionality in FF as chrome/safari?

Comment: Suggest you to use jsfiddle to make a test case and share it here.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in jsfiddle since everything relies on the actual images...

Comment: I've think I solved this. Please see your other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your image tags you need to place a hash tag before the map name.

```
<img class="pic1 day" src="img/LMday.png" usemap="#img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
```

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I cracked it - I knew it had to be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Firefox, hover events are working. Please see this example jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/JWvNC/3

```
$(function(){
    $('map area').mouseover(function(){ $('#log').append('<p>'+this.getAttribute('href') +'</p>'); });
});
```

Comment: Well, the problem is in FireFox because that's the only browser it doesn't work in.  I now know it is not the "hover" that is causing the problem but something else...